# how to set JVM Property in tomcat 8

Tags: spring, tomcat8, spring-profiles

Can you please advice how to set JVM Property in tomcat 8 ? I need to set spring.profiles.active to enable profile .

I tried to find out option to set JVM profile in tomcat admin page but this doesn't seems to be an option ...

thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind . just got it . In eclipse , we have option to specify JVM property in Run >> Run Configurations.. menu . Please see below screen shot -

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfsfp.png

Answer (score 0):

you can add in startup.bat that:

On windows:

set JAVA_HOME = /path/to/jdk
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%

On linux:

export JAVA_HOME = /path/to/jdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: tahnks but I need to setup  JAVA_OPTS as -Dspring.profiles.active=prod which will be passed to JVM during server.. the one mentioned by you will set OS environment variable .